Duplicate Runnable error in android studio
Caused by:

org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.auto.value.AutoAnnotation found in modules auto-value-1.5.3 (com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.3) and auto-value-annotations-1.6.3 (com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.3)

I am getting these errors while I try to run my code
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.s22010151.parkspotterapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.s22010151.parkspotterapp"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    // Other configurations

//    configurations {
//        cleanedAnnotations
//        compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains' , module:'annotations'
//        api.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains' , module:'annotations'
//        implementation.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains' , module:'annotations'
//    }

}



dependencies {
    //implementation ("com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.3")
//    implementation ("com.github.Inconnu08:android-ratingreviews:1.2.0")
//    {
//        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
//    }
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.0.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database:21.0.0")
    implementation ("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.2")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:21.0.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:24.0.0")
    //annotationProcessor ("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0-beta01")
    implementation ("androidx.room:room-compiler-processing-testing:2.6.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2")
    annotationProcessor ("com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2")
    implementation ("de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0")
    implementation ("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:19.0.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.3.0")
    implementation("com.karumi:dexter:6.2.1")
    implementation ("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")
    implementation("com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4")

    configurations.implementation{
        exclude("org.jetbrains", "annotations")
    }
    configurations.api{
        exclude("org.jetbrains" , "annotations")
    }
    configurations.compileOnly{
        exclude("org.jetbrains" , "annotations")
    }


   // implementation ("com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.6.3")
   // annotationProcessor ("com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.6.3")




}




This is my build.gradle.kts(:app) file how to fix this
I tried many methods from internet such as excluding but the error still exist. I cleared the cache, build clean project but the error still exist.

https://github.com/dtinit/data-transfer-project/issues/173

Have you solved the issue?
